# How to make a custom UISlider iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uislider

Hello I have a version of a desired style of UISlider implemented in android.
[image]

It was not a trivial task to implement. Now I want the same slider in iOS. I wonder if there a solution not to draw all the slider from scratch? Or any advise. Thank you.

Comment: Googled 'Custom UISlider'. Got this: https://alexanderbatalov.com/journal/2015/2/20/how-to-implement-custom-uislider-in-swift

Comment: @redent84 have you even read that post? He changed the thumb only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to do a *bit* of work, but you shouldn't need to build a complete solution from scratch.

Adding your labels will be trivial - pretty basic usage of `UISlider`

"Stretching" a track image (or tint color) left and right of center as your animation shows will be a little tricky, as the `UISlider` control has only a track / background image and a "current" image that stretches on the left-hand side.

One approach would be to set the `UISlider` track images to transparent or hidden and then "overlay" the slider on top of your "full line" and your "blue line". When the slider value changes (as it is dragged), change the frame of the blue line.

Using auto-layout and constraints would make that pretty straight-forward.

**Edit:** A really quick example. The "thumb" is purposefully moved below the "custom slider bar" to show the images...

[image]

And, this is the code to get that:

```
import UIKit

class SliderViewController: UIViewController {

    // @IBOutlets needed, but I'm just showing the "code" here
    // ...

    @IBAction func sliderValueChanged(_ sender: Any) {

        if let s = sender as? UISlider {
            updateSlider(pct: CGFloat(s.value))
        }

    }

    func updateSlider(pct: CGFloat) -> Void {

        let p = (pct - 0.5) * 2.0

        theValueLabel.text = String(format: "%0.1f", p * 10)

        leftSideValueWidth.constant = p >= 0.0 ? 0.0 : (leftSideHolderView.frame.size.width * (-p))
        rightSideValueWidth.constant = p >= 0.0 ? (rightSideHolderView.frame.size.width * p) : 0.0

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // init slider to center
        updateSlider(pct: 0.5)

        // set default left- and right-side "track" images to empty images
        theSlider.setMinimumTrackImage(UIImage(), for: .normal)
        theSlider.setMaximumTrackImage(UIImage(), for: .normal)

    }

}
```

Black `UIView` for the frame... Gray `UIView` for the "slider bar"... two transparent `UIView` for the left- / right- side framing... two blue `UIView` - one for each side. And a standard `UISlider` control. That's about it.

You could also set a custom Thumb image, if the default one is too big for your needs.

Comment: so I would need two black images and one blue image under those black images?

Comment: See the edits to my answer.

Comment: thank you it  works